# Strings pre-filled with spaces in Dart

Tags: dart

A fairly basic question :

I would like to create a string initialized to a dynamically decided number of spaces in dart. 
Here's something that worked :

```
String spaces(n) { 
  var result = new List<int>.filled(n+1,32);
  return new String.fromCharCodes(result);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can always fill the list with spaces and join them:

```dart
String spaces(n) => new List.filled(n + 1, ' ').join();
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems quite concise and easy to interpret:

```
''.padRight(32, ' ')
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/685daeea9b6f068cb847)

Comment: Very nice! This should be marked as answer..  thank you!